# Create child class object in parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

is it a good design to create object of child class in parent like the example below, it seems to be working but is it a good design, is there a better way to do that?

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Im running')
    def execute(self):
        x = child()
        x.run()
        x.myfun()
    def myfun(self):
        print('parent function')
    def run(self):
        print('parent running')

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Im running too')
    def run(self):
        print('child running')


f = parent()
f.execute()
```

Comment: To me, that seems strange. But it really depends on your specific use-case.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you did that. This code does not show that. I mean, as it is, you could simply move `execute` into the child class.

Comment: the reason I want to do is that I will have parent and many child classes, all child classes will inherit some methods from parent with no change, I will create object from parent and call a method, this method based in some inputs will create one of the child object and call a method the only exist on one of the child classes

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a good design for your problem, and not a good design generally (bar exceptions which I cannot think of any), and is definitely against OOP design and SOLID principles.

Simply in OOP design, or any other software engineering frame of mind, you want clear relations. This makes the relationship between your parent class and your child class inherently more complex. Not to mention most of the other languages (at least languages which run complied code) would not allow such thing to happen.

If you need to have an instance of one in the other and vice versa, maybe inheritance was the wrong pattern to begin with, since your classes seem to be connected in a two-way manner unlike scenarios in which inheritance is employed.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `execute` doesn't use `self` at all suggests it should be a class method, in which case you can use whichever class is actually provided to instantiate `x`.

Once you've done this, the definition of `Parent` no longer relies on any particular subclass; in fact, it doesn't rely on the fact that `Parent` is subclassed *at all*; `Parent.execute()` will continue to work.

For example,

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Im running')

    @classmethod
    def execute(cls):
        x = cls()
        x.run()
        x.myfun()

    def myfun(self):
        print('parent function')

    def run(self):
        print('parent running')


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Im running too')

    def run(self):
        print('child running')


Child.execute()
```

This will output

```
Im running
Im running too
child running
parent function
```

Since `Child.execute` isn't defined, it resolves to `Parent.execute`. But `Child` is still the first argument passed. As a result, `x` will be an instance of `Child`, not `Parent`. `x.run()` thus runs `Child.run`, but `x.myfun()` runs `Parent.myfun`.

The fact that `Parent.execute`, though, still depends on `x` having an attribute specific to `cls` suggests that you should defer restrict `execute` to using only things defined by `Parent`, and let a child override `execute` to add any child-specific behavior.

Or, `execute` *should* be an instance method, but it should simply call `self.fun`, putting the burden on the caller to call `execute` with an appropriate object.

```
c = Child()
c.execute()
```